# Set Max Value on Integer Editor Serenity

Tags: typescript

I have a quantity field on my form that uses the Integer Editor. I know I can set a max value on this field using data annotations in the form.cs like so:

```
[IntegerEditor, (MaxValue = 5)]
```

However, this max value comes from the database and I need to set this value in TypeScript, for example like:

```
this.form.Quantity.options.maxValue = someValue
```

When I try this, i am greeted with a message saying options is protected. I am just wondering if anyone knows how I can set the max value on an IntegerEditor in TypeScript based on a dynamic value?

Thanks

Comment: what is integer editor? How is it connected to TypeScript?

Comment: it's not, it is a part of "Serenity.is" but Stack Overflow wouldn't allow me to tag 'Serenity' as a filter. Serenity uses TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

I had a work around. I added a validation rule to the editor/field. I then used JQuery for an onChange event and manually changed the figure to the max quantity if the user entered a number that exceeded the max value.

Thanks.